# Font awesome icons showing up as blank boxes in live site

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Font awesome icons showing up as blank boxes in live site while it is showing up correctly locally. Added "fa" in front of the class but still not working. Any idea why?

Comment: In javascript console its giving an error as "Failed to load resource" "http://example.com/css/fontawesome-webfont.woff". But the file is present inside the specified folder i.e (css folder).

Comment: FYI: This question probably was down voted because it appears as if you didn't put any effort into it. (I'm sure you did, but the question looks as if you didn't)  In the future, try adding some code or better yet a live example and you'll have a lot more luck with getting questions answered.  For live examples JSFiddle and Plunker both work great.  I tend to use Plunker more often though.

Answer (score 2):

to test, try loading the code through their CDN rather than locally.  see if that does the trick.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: This works for me. Seems there is something wrong with my apache config.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I realized I had not put all the **fa webfonts**. You can debug your issue by going to **Inspect Element -> Network** and then see which files are resulting in a **404 error**.

Go to their initiators and upload those files. It will start working again.